A question about metric and integration
The components of the metric in the primed and unprimed coordinate bases are related by this formula: $$g_{i'j'}=g_{kl}x^{k}_{\phantom{x}, i'}x^{l}_{\phantom{x},j'}$$
If I call the Cartesian coordinates my unprimed coordinates and the polar coordinates my primed coordinates and write the equations in full, I get this:
$$\left\{\begin{array}{1}\left(\frac{\partial{x}}{\partial{r}}\right)^2+\left(\frac{\partial{y}}{\partial{r}}\right)^2=1\\\frac{\partial{x}}{\partial{r}}\frac{\partial{x}}{\partial{\theta}}+\frac{\partial{y}}{\partial{r}}\frac{\partial{y}}{\partial{\theta}}=0\\\left(\frac{\partial{x}}{\partial{\theta}}\right)^2+\left(\frac{\partial{y}}{\partial{\theta}}\right)^2=r^2\end{array}\right.$$
I am curious to know how can one solve this system of coupled non-linear partial differential equations and show that it integrates into $\left\{\begin{array}{1}x=r\cos{\theta}\\y=r\sin{\theta}\end{array}\right.$. There must exist some substitutions that render these equations integrable I assume?
Also, I would be thankful if someone could comment on this issue: there seems to be 3 equations for 2 unknowns. Doesn't this imply that the system is overdetermined and no solution exists (which obviously is not the fact)?
Thank you for reading.
